# File Upload Styling in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've a html formular in a part of a website, which only specific administration users can access. In this form, you can upload csv files. As only a small group of users can do this, the functionality is more important than the styling. So I decided not to do the usual trick overlaying a div over the field. I just want to archive one thing: The text in the field should look the in Chrome the same as in FF (vertical and horizontal centered text).

Here you can see the both renderings:

FF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHhG.png

Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BFHu.png

HTML-Code:

```
<input type="file" class="button blue full-width" name="csv_file" id="csv_file">
```

CSS-Styles:

```
color: #fff;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0 10%;
background-image: url("../images/item-hover-button-addtocart-normal.png");
border: medium none;
margin-bottom: 10px;
background-color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix one of the issues by adding this css:

```
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    margin: 1px 0;
    height: 48px;
}
```

This makes the button take up more height like in FF and also makes the text vertically centered..
Not so sure how to horizontally center it though, maybe someone else might know a trick.

A jsfiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/bcwk8qvt/

[edit]
You can make it centered horizontally by adding most of your original CSS to a div wrapped around the input field like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bcwk8qvt/3/
You still need to keep some of the css on the input field too though for FF to show it the same way.

Comment: The vertically centering is working perfect, thanks. But I still have problems with the horizontal centering. I tried your solution and wrapped the input in a div with the styles in your correctly working fiddle, but no reaction. The important part is the text-align: center, isn't it?

Comment: That is an important part yes, is it just not working in chrome or? But if the fiddle works, your code should work too, maybe create a fiddle with your current code?